# how to check if props.hisory.goBack has value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i have to implement custom back button. If the path is starting from `'https://example.com/'` then `props.history.goBack` will not go back and stops. But when user directly enter say `'https://example.com/places/u1/new'` and clicks on the button `<button onClick={props.history.goBack}>back</button>` then browser goes back to empty page. Please help me find a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you use class component then you have to use button
 onClick={()=>this.props.history.goBack()}

and if you are using functional component

onClick={()=>props.history.goBack()}

Comment: That is true but, you enter a url manually say `https://example.com/places/new` and click back as soon as you enter that link browser will take you back to empty page. how can we prevent that?